# how to convert json to java Obj using flexjson?

Tags: java, json, flexjson

Yes. It is my code what convert java obj to JSON using flexjson.  It is ok by the test. But I don't know how to convert JSON to java Obj. Anybody knows? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
        /**
         * convert java obj to json using flexjson 2.1.
         * 
         * @param obj
         * @return jsonStr
         */
    public static String bean2Json(Object obj) {
        JSONSerializer serilizer = new JSONSerializer();
        return serilizer.serialize(obj);
    }

     /**
      * convert json to java obj using flexjson 2.1.
      * 
      * @param jsonStr
      * @param objClass
      *
      * @return obj
      */
    public static <T> T json2Bean(String jsonStr, Class<T> objClass) {
      // TODO
    }
```

Comment: public static <T> T json2Bean(String jsonStr, Class<T> objClass) {
  JSONDeserializer<T> js = new JSONDeserializer<T>();
  return js.deserialize(jsonStr, objClass);
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import flexjson.JSONDeserializer;
import flexjson.JSONSerializer;

public class DeserializerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JSONSerializer serilizer = new JSONSerializer();
        Apple oneApple = new Apple(123);
        String appleString = serilizer.serialize(oneApple);

        // Convert Apple String to Apple object here
        Apple deserializedApple = new JSONDeserializer<Apple>().deserialize( appleString );
        System.out.println("AppleID: "+deserializedApple.appleID);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Apple {
    public int appleID;

    public Apple(){}

    public Apple(int pAppleID){
        this.appleID=pAppleID;
    }
}
```

The expected output should be AppleID: 123

Hope it helps